# How to position side by side images covering the whole page with no overlap?

Tags: graphics

I have a single 8.5 x 11in landscape page. I need to cover this page with four side by side images 4.25 x 5.5in each leaving no margin and overlap. Image attached.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[paperwidth=8.5in,paperheight=11in,landscape, margin=0mm, 
left=0cm, right=0cm, top=0cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\centering
\includegraphics[page=1,width=5.5in,height=4.25in,keepaspectratio]{koala}
\includegraphics[page=1,width=5.5in,height=4.25in,keepaspectratio]{koala}
\includegraphics[page=1,width=5.5in,height=4.25in,keepaspectratio]{koala}
\includegraphics[page=1,width=5.5in,height=4.25in,keepaspectratio]{koala}
\end{document}
```

[image: koala]
[image: 4koalas]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you are already loading `tikz`.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[paperwidth=8.5in,paperheight=11in,landscape, margin=0mm, 
left=0cm, right=0cm, top=0cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
\foreach \anchor in {north west,south west,north east, south east}
{\node[inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt,anchor=\anchor] 
at (current page.center)
{\includegraphics[page=1,width=5.5in,height=4.25in,keepaspectratio]{koala}}; }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

But you can do without:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[paperwidth=8.5in,paperheight=11in,landscape, margin=0mm, 
left=0cm, right=0cm, top=0cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0} 
\noindent\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}c@{}}
\includegraphics[page=1,width=5.5in,height=4.25in,keepaspectratio]{koala}
&\includegraphics[page=1,width=5.5in,height=4.25in,keepaspectratio]{koala}\\
\includegraphics[page=1,width=5.5in,height=4.25in,keepaspectratio]{koala}
&\includegraphics[page=1,width=5.5in,height=4.25in,keepaspectratio]{koala}
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Love it! Is it possible to have a lot of marmots instead of koalas?

Answer (score 1):

Without Ti*k*Z, with a little negative `\vspace`.

Please note that `keepaspectratio` with *both* `width=...` and `height=...` makes no sense.

(Change example-image-a into koala in your actual document.)

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[paperwidth=8.5in,paperheight=11in,landscape, margin=0mm, 
left=0cm, right=0cm, top=0cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\centering
\includegraphics[page=1,width=5.5in,height=4.25in]{example-image-a}%
\includegraphics[page=1,width=5.5in,height=4.25in]{example-image-a}

\vspace{-.1\baselineskip}\includegraphics[page=1,width=5.5in,height=4.25in]{example-image-a}%
\includegraphics[page=1,width=5.5in,height=4.25in]{example-image-a}
\end{document}
```

[image]